# How do I get different click positions in a single ImageView

Tags: android, image-processing, imageview, android-imageview

I am working on an application in which I need to implement Hot Spot kind of thing. Hot Spot is actually an image having different sections in it, when user clicks on different portions of that image it will reflect in different results accordingly, so my problem is that how can I get the click of these different portions which are present in the single Image, also if I get the X-Coordinates and Y-Coordinates of the same Image then how should I maintain it in different screen resolution. I am displaying a demo image with my question
[image]

Here its a single image, now I just want to get click of the four section displayed here, for e.g. if I click on section no.4 I can show another image etc.
Please help me to sort this out, any help would be appreciable.
Thank you.

Comment: you should implement your onTouch, and use the MotionEvent to get the coords of the touch

Comment: use OnTouchListener and ImageView.getImageMatrix()
.invert()

Comment: @blackbelt, are you talking about the getX() and getY() methods ???

Comment: ehm yes I am. What's wrong with those?

Comment: I have tried that but its not giving constant values for different screen resolutions, How can I handle that ??

Comment: @SalmanKhan OnTouchListener?

Comment: ImageView.getImageMatrix().invert() , I am talking about that ...

Comment: @SalmanKhan it inverts the Matrix used for image drawing, did you try it?

Comment: No I don't have any idea about that, How can I get pixel position using that ???

Comment: @SalmanKhan read Matrix docs carefuly

Comment: @SalmanKhan this is quick: 3 or 4 lines of code...

Comment: @pskink, I am not able to find those 3 or 4 lines you are talking about, if u can explain the concept then it would be much helpful for me.

Comment: if. you have inverted Matrix just call mapPoints on it

Comment: @pskink, I am not getting you why you want to invert the matrix ??

Comment: because the inverted Matrix maps from ImageView coordinates to bitmap coordinates

Comment: float xCoords = event.getX();
    float yCoords = event.getY();

    Log.d("Coords ","Coords x" + xCoords);
    Log.d("Coords ","Coords y" + yCoords);
    
    float arr[] = new float[1];
arr[0] = xCoords;
arr[1] = yCoords;
Matrix imgMatrix = img.getImageMatrix();
imgMatrix.mapPoints(arr);
img.setImageMatrix(imgMatrix);

Comment: I have done something like that, but don't know how to get Bitmap coords

Comment: You are just saying use "inverted matrix", I am not getting this my friend.

Comment: see Matrix.invert() http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html#invert(android.graphics.Matrix)

Comment: @SalmanKhan your issue solved?. I faced same issue, so how to solve this issue... Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a library for this, though it does lot more than what I want to achieve but its good to use this one.

https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView

Answer (score 0):

Finally I used below library and set some logic and made solution, as of my expectation.

> https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView